# Page Specific Javascript code in rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have seen many answers to similar posts on Stackoverflow and I tried implementing it but it is not working. I have done the following things

1) Removed //= require_tree . from assets/javascripts/application.js

2) Added //= require users in the assets/javascripts/application.js (where users.js is my javascript file in the same folder as the application.js resides)

In my new.html.erb I have included the following line

```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "users" %>
```

3) users.js contains simple javascript code like "alert(6)"

When I make request to users/new thru localhost I do not get any alert although I can see my users.js included in the html but there is no code in that.
Can anyone please help me on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have included `users.js` inside `application.js`, you should add `application.js` to the page

In **new.html.erb**, replace `users` with `application`

Remove this line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "users" %>
```

And add this line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: I said I have included users.js in the same folder as in application.js. I am not sure what do you mean by including user.js inside application.js?

Comment: It is not working. Also I would like to mention that the above line include application is already there in application.html.erb under layouts folder